# Possible to instantiate object from another objects method (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Is there a way to create a new object from the method of another object like so?

```
var _object = {
  _method:function(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

var b = new _object.method('Joe')
```

Comment: Need an underscore before _method in the call.

Comment: Sure, what's wrong with what you're doing now *(other than the missing `_`)*? If you expect there to be a relationship between `b` and `_object`, unfortunately there will be none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you're doing it correctly. The only problem is that you misspelled `._method`. Change it to this:

```
var b = new _object._method('Joe')
```

Comment: Blah realized my problem was because i was using coffeescript and in that it was returning only the last method inside the method object and not the object itself. I just needed to to tell the method to return itself at the end of the function